# Can't reverse facebook plugin display:none

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, facebook

I'm at my wits end.

I wanted to use display:none on facebook plugin and then reverse it with Angular or jQuery to bring it back into the view.

But somehow once I add display:none on facebook plugin iframe it stays like that forever. I also added images and other divs and when I reverse it they appear.

Someone must have encountered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Facebook plugin is rendered when it's iframe loaded the plugin URL. When it's rendering, the plugin gets a width and height and all elements inside the plugin get positioned. So if you hide a Facebook plugin initially, it will be rendered without any width or height.

A workaround would be to reactivate the iframe with JavaScript, by removing and adding the URL for example.

Comment: Thank you, though specifying the iframe width in the css also does trick.